# Making a flash icon work in flutter by turning on the flash when the icon is pressed

Tags: flutter, camera-flash

I am making a camera app with a button that will be able to turn the flash on and off. 
When the flash is not on I would like for the **flash_off** icon to be displayed.

However, my problem is trying to make the flash turn on and the icon change to **flash_auto** when the flash icon is pressed. I tried doing something which you can see down below, but I am still new to Flutter and learning the syntax so I do not think it is right.

I also declared the flash variable as a static bool because it would not allow me to declare it as a regular boolean, "static bool flash = false"

```
  const IconButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 30), // right 30
            onPressed: null,
            icon: Icon(
              flash ? Icons.flash_on : Icons.flash_off,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            iconSize: 50,
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                flash = !flash;
                flash ? _cameraController.setFlashMode(FlashMode.off);
              });
             
              //flash?_cameraController.setFlashMode(FlashMode.torch) : 

            }),
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you want three options for icons you can't use a simple true/false check, you'll need an array.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FlashPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const FlashPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FlashPage> createState() => _FlashPageState();
}

class _FlashPageState extends State<FlashPage> {
  int flashStatus = 0;
  List<Icon> flash = [
    Icon(Icons.flash_on),
    Icon(Icons.flash_off),
    Icon(Icons.flash_auto)
  ];
  
  List<FlashMode> flashMode = [
    FlashMode.always,
    FlashMode.off,
    FlashMode.auto
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flash demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: IconButton(
              icon: flash[flashStatus],
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  flashStatus = (flashStatus + 1) % 3;
                  _cameraController.setFlashMode(flashMode[flashStatus]);
                });
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code, however, I am getting an error due to the "int flashStatus = 0" I think I may be placing it in the wrong location. Is this the right way? Or can you try it and see what I am doing wrong? I have inserted the code down below @Gerry

Comment: children: <Widget>[
              int flashStatus = 0,
              List<Icons> flash = [Icons.flash_on, Icons.flash_off, Icons.flash_auto];
              const IconButton(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 30), // right 30
                icon: flash[flashStatus],
                iconSize: 50,
                onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      flashStatus = (flashStatus + 1) % 3;
                    });
                  }),
                ),

Comment: @Serenity I have included the whole working code. Please confirm and then mark the answer as correct with the green tick.

Comment: hello I have tried your code however, the flash does not work still.

Comment: The code is just for the visual aspect of cycling through the different modes.

Comment: @Serenity To use the flash just create a list of FlashMode with the various options and pass the flashStatus into the list. I have updated my answer. Let me know if this works.

Comment: I will try to implement it now, however, where did you define camera controller? and how did you define it?

Comment: @Serenity I am just going based off your code sample. I assumed you have defined it already in the stateful widget this IconButton you want is in.